# Finding the sum of the first row and the diagonal in a 2d array

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix

I need to find the sum of all the integers in the first row and the sum of all the numbers in the diagonal. The code I have gives me a huge incorrect number for the sum, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
int i,j, matrix [10][10], sum_row[10];
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i <10;++i)
{
    printf("\n\n");
    for (j = 0; j <10; ++j)
    {
        matrix [i][j] = rand()%10;
        printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("\n\n");
matrix[i][j]= rand()%10;
for (i = 0; i<10; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j<10; ++j)
    {
       sum_row[i] += matrix[i][j];
    }
}
printf("%d", sum_row);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should start by trying for smaller matrices and so on

Comment: The line after `printf("\n\n");` should be removed.  It's writing to an invalid location beyond the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not initialize `sum_row`, automatic variables are not zero initialized, their values are indeterminate. So the initial value of the elements of `sum_row` are indeterminate. So on this line:

```
sum_row[i] += matrix[i][j];
```

you are adding values to an indeterminate initial value which will result in an indeterminate end value. You can change the declaration to this:

```
sum_row[10] = {0}
```

to zero initialize all the elements.

This line looks like a typo:

```
printf("%d", sum_row);
```

and probably was meant to be:

```
printf("%d\n", sum_row[0]);
                      ^^^
```

You also should remove the final:

```
matrix[i][j]= rand()%10;
```

after the initial loop since it will be using invalid indices for both `i` and `j`.

To obtain the sum of the diagonal you just need a new variable initialized to zero and only add an element to that sum when `i == j` within the final for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For finding the sum in a row keep i as constant and change j

For finding the sum of diagonal elements keep i = j.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
int i,j, matrix [10][10], sum_row=0, sum_diag=0;
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i <10;++i)
{
    printf("\n\n");
    for (j = 0; j <10; ++j)
    {
        matrix [i][j] = rand()%10;
        printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("\n\n");
    for (j = 0; j<10; ++j)
    {
    /* i = 0 indicates row 0 */
       sum_row += matrix[0][j];
    /* i = j indicates diagnoal */
       sum_diag += matrix[j][j];
    }
printf("row sum: %d, diag sum: %d", sum_row, sum_diag);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have not calculated sum of diagonal elements. You have calculated only sum of row elements. In that it seems there are 3 mistakes.

1. You have not initialised the sum_row[10]. You have to initialise it to zero before using it.
2. printf("%d", sum_row); this statement tries to print address of sum_row[] array. If you want the value to be printed then use sum_row['some index'].
3. matrix[i][j]= rand()%10;   This statement may give error b'caz you have declare matrix as an array of size 10*10 but you are trying to access matrix[10][10] which is 11*11 th element

To calculate sum of diagonal elements, take some variable lets say sum, initialise it to zero, and increment it while calculating sum of row elements. It is as below

sum=0;

sum_row[10]={0};

for (i = 0; i<10; ++i)

{

```
for (j = 0; j<10; ++j)

{

   sum_row[i] += matrix[i][j];

   if(i==j)

   sum+=matrix[i][j];

}
```

}

printf("Sum of diagonal elements: %d\n",sum);

for(i=0;i<10;i++)

printf("Sum of elements in row %d is %d",i+1,sum_row[i]);

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialise

```
sum_row[10] = { 0 };
```

if you had used i++, then you could have skipped the line

```
 matrix[i][j]= rand()%10;    // then second one

 for(i=0; i<10; i++)

 printf(%d\n, sum_row[i]);
```